# datetime in Javascript alert more 2 GMT hours

Tags: javascript, datetime

Working with datetime in Javascript(apache/php/js project) and making alert for debugging I get message like "Sun Nov 30 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200 ",
though in var time was not specified at all. That is gvfery confusing...
Which is the best and safe way to get rid of this GMT 2 hours ?

Comment: Sounds normal.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date if you want to create a different format.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toISOString()`, e.g:

```
var myDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

For older browsers, which don't natively support this method, the function definition can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString